# Which way is better to call a function static way or object way ?

Tags: php, oop

Hi
 I'm new to OOPS, Can you guys suggest me which way is better to call a function of a class in PHP and why? the scenario is as follows.

```
class A
{
     function B (){}
}
```

Which method will take less resource to call the function B

```
1. A::B();
```

or

```
2. $obj = new A();  
   $obj->B();
```

Comment: You should not ask the question `which one takes less resources` in regards to static / non-static methods (and it would be micro-optimalisation if anything). It should be clear from the function: does the function operate on an object, alter the object, need object variables? Then it's probably a non-static. Does the function need no references to an instance? Then it could be a static.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the second way creates an unnecessary temporary object, so the first one is faster. But if you have an object created anyway, it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in [PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) calling non-static methods statically is deprecated so you will get an error.
Secondly it is better to call the method object way so code will be backward compatible.